# Expected specifier-list before "MainViewController / Method -x not found return type defaults to id

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following imports in my **EquivalenceClassGroup**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
```

but then in my property in EquivalanceClassGroup.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) MainViewController *myController;
```

I get this error: "Expected specifier-list before **MainViewController** when compiling

If I change the import to: `@class MainViewController` and comment out the import of **MainViewController.h** that error goes away but then then XCode can't find the methods in my **MainViewController** from **EquivalenceClassGroup**.m so from here:

```
-(id)initWithLetterNumbers: (int)numOfLettersInWord enteredLetter: (NSString *) str  controller:(UIViewController *)controller {
    myController = (MainViewController *) controller;
    letterArray = [myController getLetterArray];
    [myController getLetterArray];
```

I get: "Method `-getLetterArray` not found return type defaults to id" on that last line

I have this method defined in the **MainViewController**: `-(NSArray*)getLetterArray;`
and there are no errors in that interface file or the m file.  In the equivalence class if I type in [myController then space, I cant seem to find any methods.

From the **MainViewController** class I do import the **EquivalenceClassGroup** and use the methods without any problems

Comment: in which file you are writing #import "MainViewController.h"

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you import the `MainViewController.h` file in your .m file. All the `@class` does is tell the interface that there is such a class, but it doesn't tell it anything about the class. That is what `#import` essentially does. The `@class` in the .h file is just good programming practice to make sure that you are doubling importing or anything. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write #import "MainViewController.h"  in EquivalanceClassGroup.h file and 
@class MainViewController in MainViewController.h file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@class MainViewController
```

in your EquivalenceClassGroup.h

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
```

in EquivalenceClassGroup.m

This is called "forward declaration" and is quite common.

Comment: I missed that import in the second class. Thanks